# PHP Script: How to optimize

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, optimization, ram

I wrote a script for a wordpress plugin. This wordpress plugin handles the import from XML files to products. Because the plugin normally overwrites the existing product with the new values, I added some custom code to add the new product infos instand of overwritting them.

The first problem was that I got "Ram exhausted" because I used some other plugin methods which calls a wordpress query and so on. So I fixed that and now I'am using directly the SQL query instand of calling the function and the function calls the query and so on...

But now I have another problem. The code is working. Everything appears and is set where it is supposed to be!
But now the script is slowing down the entire progress.. Either my Ram gets exhausted or my SQL Database... So I'am supposed to optimize my code.

I already took two looks but in my eyes everything I call and save is necessary... Does anyone knows how I can optimize my plugin?

```
function wp_all_import_before_xml_import($import_id){

    if($import_id !== 72 || $import_id !== 88){

        unlink("wp_all_import.txt");

        //Datenbankverbindung aufbbauen
        $database = new mysqli("localhost", "wordpress_dc", "censored", "wordpress_5");
        $database_gk = new mysqli("localhost", "wordpress_8", "censored", "wordpress_6");

        //Datenbankverbindung checken
        if($database->connect_errno){
            $myfile = fopen("wp_all_import.txt", "a");
            fwrite($myfile, "+++Couldn't connect to database!+++\n\n");
            fclose($myfile);
        }

        if($database_gk->connect_errno){
            $myfile = fopen("wp_all_import.txt", "a");
            fwrite($myfile, "+++Couldn't connect to database!+++\n\n");
            fclose($myfile);
        }

        //WP_ALL_IMPORT Tabelleninhalt löschen
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM `wp_all_import`';
        $database->query($sql);

        //Holen alle Posts
        $values_gkw = $database_gk->query("SELECT `ID` FROM `fWR6qIN_posts` where post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish'");

        while($row = $values_gkw->fetch_assoc()){
            $id = $row["ID"];
            $pid = $id;
            $title = get_the_title($pid);

            $repeater = $database_gk->query("SELECT Count(meta_key) AS cnt FROM `fWR6qIN_postmeta` Where meta_key like 'product_shops_%_price' AND (post_id = $pid)");

            while($row = $repeater->fetch_assoc()){
                $count = $row["cnt"];
            }

            for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
                $price_meta = "product_shops_".$i."_price";
                $price_old_meta = "product_shops_".$i."_price_old";
                $link_meta = "product_shops_".$i."_link";
                $shop_meta = "product_shops_".$i."_shop";

                $price;
                $price_old;
                $link;
                $shop;

                $details = $database_gk->query("SELECT `meta_key`, `meta_value` FROM `fWR6qIN_postmeta` WHERE post_id = '$pid' AND (meta_key like '$price_meta' OR meta_key like '$price_old_meta' OR meta_key like '$link_meta' OR meta_key like '$shop_meta')");

                while($row_meta = $details->fetch_assoc()){
                    if($row_meta["meta_key"] == $price_meta){
                        $price = $row_meta["meta_value"];
                    }elseif($row_meta["meta_key"] == $price_old_meta){
                        $price_old = $row_meta["meta_value"];
                    }elseif($row_meta["meta_key"] == $link_meta){
                        $link = $row_meta["meta_value"];
                    }elseif($row_meta["meta_key"] == $shop_meta){
                        $shop = $row_meta["meta_value"];
                    }else{
                        $myfile = fopen("wp_all_import.txt", "a");
                        fwrite($myfile, "Is not matching!\n");
                        fclose($myfile);
                    }
                }

                //Checken ob Product Shop Row noch in Datenbank vorhanden
                $values = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `wp_all_import_xml` WHERE name = '$title' AND price = '$price' AND shop = '$shop' AND url = '$link'");

                $count_values = mysqli_num_rows($values);

                //Falls nein, lösche diese Product Shop Row aus Datenbank
                //Falls ja, füge Product Shop Row der "echten" Datenbank hinzu
                if($count_values == 0){
                    $sql = "DELETE FROM `wp_all_import` WHERE pid = '$pid' AND shop = '$shop' AND price = '$price' AND link = '$link'";
                    $database->query($sql);

                    /*
                    $myfile = fopen("wp_all_import.txt", "a");
                    fwrite($myfile, "Would delete! " . $pid . " Preis: " . $price . " Link: " . $link . "\n");
                    fclose($myfile);
                    */

                }elseif($count_values == 1){
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_all_import` (pid, price, price_old, link, shop) VALUES ('$pid', '$price', '$price_old', '$link', '$shop')";

                    if($database->query($sql) === TRUE){

                    }else{
                        $myfile = fopen("wp_all_import.txt", "a");
                        fwrite($myfile, "Product ERROR!\n");
                        fclose($myfile);
                    }

                    /*
                    $myfile = fopen("wp_all_import.txt", "a");
                    fwrite($myfile, "Would insert! " . $pid . " Preis: " . $price . " Link: " . $link . "\n");
                    fclose($myfile);
                    */

                }else{
                    $myfile = fopen("wp_all_import.txt", "a");
                    fwrite($myfile, "ERROR by detecting Product (More than 1 Row return by SQL!): " .$title. " Preis: " .$price. " Shop: " .$shop. " Link: " .$link. "\t num_rows: " .$count_values. "\n\n");
                    fclose($myfile);
                }

                $price = null;
                $price_old = null;
                $link = null;
                $shop = null;
                $price_meta = null;
                $price_old_meta = null;
                $link_meta = null;
                $shop_meta = null;

            }

            $title = null;
            $count = null;
        }
    }   
}

function my_saved_post($pid, $xml_node){
    $title = get_the_title($pid);

    if($title != "End of Import" || $title !== "Start of Import" || $title !== "Start of Import1" || $title !== "Start of Import2" || $title !== "Start of Import3" || $title !== "Start of Import4" || $title !== "Start of Import5"){

        //Datenbankverbindung aufbbauen
        $database = new mysqli("localhost", "wordpress_dc", "Q037u_PnMf", "wordpress_5");
        $title = get_the_title($pid);

        //Datenbankverbindung checken
        if($database->connect_errno){
            $myfile = fopen("wp_all_import.txt", "a");
            fwrite($myfile, "+++Couldn't connect to database!+++\n\n");
            fclose($myfile);
        }

        //Anzahl an an Product Shop Rows holen
        $aktueller_counter = -1;
        while(have_rows('product_shops', $pid)): the_row();
            $aktueller_counter = $aktueller_counter + 1;
        endwhile;

        if($aktueller_counter == -1){
            $aktueller_counter = 0;
        }   

        $pic = get_field("product_gallery_external_0_url", $pid);
        $alt = get_field("product_gallery_external_0_alt", $pid); 

        delete_row('product_gallery_external', 1, $pid);

        if($pic != null && $alt != null){
            update_post_meta($pid, 'fifu_image_url', $pic);
            update_post_meta($pid, 'fifu_image_alt', $alt);
        }

        //Preis, Alter Preis, Link und Shop holen
        $price = get_field("product_shops_0_price", $pid);
        $price_old = get_field("product_shops_0_price_old", $pid);
        $link = get_field("product_shops_0_link", $pid);
        $shop = get_field("product_shops_0_shop", $pid)->ID;


        //Holen Preis, Alten Preis, Link und Shop aus "echter" Datenbenk, wo PID = PID Und Shop = Shop
        $value = $database->query("SELECT `price`, `price_old`, `link`, `shop` FROM `wp_all_import` WHERE pid = '$pid' AND shop = '$shop' AND link = '$link'");
        $count_values = mysqli_num_rows($values);

        //Itterieren über Rückgabewert(e) der Datenbank
        while($row = $value->fetch_assoc()){
            //Wenn Shop = Shop und Preis oder Alter Preis haben sich geändert, dann lösche Eintrag aus der "echten" Datenbank, wo PID = PID, SHOP = SHOP und PREIS = PREIS (Könnten mehere Sein!)
            //Anschließend füge neuen Wert in Dantenbank ein
            if($row["shop"] == $shop && $row["link"] == $link && ($row["price"] != $price || $row["price_old"] != $price_old)){

                $rprice = $row["price"];
                $rprice_old = $row["price_old"];
                $rshop = $row["shop"];

                $sql = "DELETE FROM `wp_all_import` WHERE pid = '$pid' AND shop = '$rshop' AND price = '$rprice'";
                $database->query($sql);

                $sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_all_import` (pid, price, price_old, link, shop) VALUES ('$pid', '$rprice', '$rprice_old', '$link', '$rshop')";
                $database->query($sql);
            }
        }

        //Holen Preis, Alten Preis, Link und Shop aus "echter" Datenbenk, wo PID = PID
        $values = $database->query("SELECT `price`, `price_old`, `link`, `shop` FROM `wp_all_import` WHERE pid = '$pid'");
        $count_values = mysqli_num_rows($values);

        //Itterieren über Rückgabewert(e) der Datenbank
        while($row = $values->fetch_assoc()) {
            $row = array(
                'price' => $row["price"],
                'price_old' => $row["price_old"],
                'currency' => 'euro',
                'portal' => '',
                'link' => $row["link"],
                'shop' => $row["shop"]
            );

            //Wenn ungleich Preis = Preis, Alter Preis = Alter Preis, Link = Link und Shop = Shop, dann füge Row hinzu, da nicht gerade hinzugefügte Row aus Import und Import hat alle Product Shop Rows gelöscht

            //Ansonsten füge Eintrag in Datenbank ein, da eben neu hinzugefügt durch Import
            if(!($row["price"] == $price && $row["price_old"] == $price_old && $row["link"] == $link && $row["shop"] == $shop)){
                $j = add_row('product_shops', $row, $pid);
            }else{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_all_import` (pid, price, price_old, link, shop) VALUES ('$pid', '$price', '$price_old', '$link', '$shop')";
                $database->query($sql);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Executing MySQL queries inside of loops is generally a bad idea and could be a culprit for the slowness. Take a look at transactions which will also help you with data integrity since if you run into an error midway through your script you can revert the changes to the database and not worry about it being in a broken state. See MySQL documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html edit: looks like you're doing something similar with fopen and fwrite. For appending multiple lines to a file you should build the sting in your loop and then write once to the file

Comment: I just write something in a file if something went wrong. But nothing goes wrong actual. So that shouldn't be the error at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

Terribly inefficient:

```
$array = SELECT ...;
foreach ($array as $item)
{
    do some SQL with $item
}
```

Instead, look for a way to do all if it at once.  Examples:

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...,

DELETE FROM a JOIN b ON ... WHERE ...
```

Can be improved:

```
DELETE a row
INSERT replacement for that row
```

Instead:

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

and be sure to have a suitable

```
UNIQUE(pid, shop, price)
```

so that it knows which row you are "upserting".

You mentioned XML and running out of RAM?  I don't see any XML functions?  XML can be a memory hog.

You should check for errors after each `query()`.

I hope you are not reconnecting multiple times per run.